# Error (JSON 404): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF/

Tags: vmc

---

When I run "vmc info", I get an error : Error (JSON 404):

cloud@rest:~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/rest/log$ vmc info -t

```
>>>
REQUEST: get http://api.mwt.needforspeed.info/info
RESPONSE_HEADERS:
    content_length : 239
    date : Thu, 11 Oct 2012 07:32:17 GMT
    content_type : text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    content_encoding : gzip
    server : Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
    vary : Accept-Encoding
RESPONSE: [404]
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /info was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at api.mwt.needforspeed.info Port 80</address>
</body></html>
<<<
Error (JSON 404): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /info was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at api.mwt.needforspeed.info Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have apache webserver running on port 80.

If you install cloudfoundry to a plain vanilla Ubuntu, it will install nginx as a webserver.
So first stop your apache, normally with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and than check that your nginx (router in cloudfoundry's term) is running:

```
source ~/.cloudfoundry_deployment_local
~/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev -n rest status router
```

please note that you need the extra **-n rest** parameter as it seems that you didn't use the default development name: **dev_box**